# Evaluate if at least one column contains the value "Yes"

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, expression

In QGIS, I'm trying to input either 'Yes' or 'No' for a new field based upon the input of values of another 9 fields. I've attached a screenshot of what I'm trying to accomplish. Essentially if there is a 'Yes' in any of the 9 previous fields, then the new field will input 'Yes'. If however all 9 fields are *NULL*, then the new field will input 'No'.

[image]

Comment: Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for this function:

`coalesce(NULL, 'Yes', NULL, 'No')`

'Yes'

`coalesce(NULL, NULL, NULL, 'No')`

'No'

> Returns the first non-NULL value from the expression list. This
>   function can take any number of arguments.

So it will return the first non-NULL value it finds so if you make No the last value it will fallback to that value and report that.

`coalesce("Field1", "Field2", "Field3", 'No')`